# Themes with variable width or single columns? I want to display source code

Tags: php, themes, code

I've just set up a new WordPress blog, and as a developer I want to post some source code as well. Now I found the suitable plug-ins I need, and also a sleek theme, or so I thought.

The problem is the width, it's just way too small. Even if I pick the option this theme has to only use a single column, it's still not wide enough.

I guess my choices as a programmer wanting a theme to display my code correctly will be rather shallow, but there must be something I can do?

Here's the first post I made on this blog:
http://www.froginvasion.be/blog/?p=11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be good if you can pick up a theme that is wide enough for your requirements. Probably a theme based on 1140 grid system will work good for you. 
That said, if you still want to use your existing theme then you can edit theme's `style.css` , on line 76 you can delete `max-width:1000px`
After this the page will occupy the entire available space .